# R - unique comma separated values

Tags: r

i've comma-separeted values like "black,white,black" and i want unique comma separated values:

```
a <- "black, white, black"
```

How do I get a unique comma-separated value? Expacted:

```
res <- "black, white"
```

Many thanks in advance for your probably very quick answers again.

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below

```
> toString(unique(unlist(strsplit(a,",\\s+"))))
[1] "black, white"
```

or

```
> toString(unique(trimws(scan(text = a, what = character(),sep = ","))))
Read 3 items
[1] "black, white"
```